# Better solution for non-model request on CakePHP1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

there are some parameter withought relayting a model.

```
Router::connect("/ctrl/action/:mode/:year"      ,
    array('controller' => 'ctrl', 'action' => 'action'),
    array('mode' => 'modea|modeb', 'year' => '[12][0-9]{3}'));
```

How to validate and sanitize?

Should I create dummy model?
or Implement on a component?

Comment: When/where/why/how and most of all *what* do you need to validate here?

Comment: thank you in advance. if user access /ctrl/action/modec/5010 it's wrong I should validate the request and convert modec => modea(default) 5010 => date('Y') :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your current route wouldn't match `/ctrl/action/modea/5010`, so it would fall through to another route, most likely the standard route, which would dispatch the request to `Ctrl_controller::action('modea', 5010)`. I.e. you basically have the same result.

The best thing to do is probably to just skip the route, since it doesn't really route anything anywhere it wouldn't go anyway. Just validate in your controller action before using the values:

```
function action($mode, $year) {
    if (!in_array($mode, array('modea', 'modeb')) || $year < 1900 || 3000 < $year) {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    ... business as usual ...
}
```

Or:

```
function action($mode, $year) {
    switch ($mode) {
        case 'modea' :
            ...
            break;
        case 'modeb' :
            ...
            break;
        default :
            $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
}
```

Or some combination thereof. Unless the `$mode` and `$year` variables have anything to do with your database/model, you do not want to make a model for it. Models do validation, because that's an important step before putting stuff into the database, but that doesn't mean they're the only part of the app that can or should do validation.